# Authorize.net CIM or using the module's storage

Tags: joomla, paypal, payment-gateway, authorize.net

this site is intended to allow users to sign up and pay for a service, they will be able to pay using Paypal and Authorize.net

since I am using two different payment gateways, it makes me wonder where I want to keep the user information.

Authorize.net offers CIM, but some users will pay with paypal therefore Authorize.net won't have all user's information

Would the best solution then be to not use CIM and store everything within my member database module?

for the record I am using OSE for Joomla for my subscriber service

Comment: Hey by any chance do you know how it works using free-merchant.com as a payment gateway? I'm kind of new at this and was wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorize.Net's CIM API is really only useful for creating payment profiles so you don't have to store customer credit card information. Although storing other information using CIM can be handy, you'll usually want to store that locally for easier management.